# Method for using F4 key without pressing function button on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, applescript, shortcut

I'm using a program that uses the <kbd>F4</kbd> key as an important shortcut which I use heavily.

Every time I want to press <kbd>F4</kbd> on my MacBook Pro also have to press the <kbd>fn</kbd> button.

Is there a possibility (such as with an AppleScript?) that something could detect if I'm using that program and allow me to avoid pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> and let me use the shortcut just with the <kbd>F4</kbd> key?

Comment: Have you tried going into "System Preferences > Keyboard" and checking the box next to "Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>TEXTEDIT</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.TextEdit</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>flipf4</name>
    <identifier>flipf4</identifier>
    <only>TEXTEDIT</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD, KeyCode::F4</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F4, KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: sorry but how can I insert this xml snippet?

Comment: Save it as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`, open KeyRemap4MacBook, press the Reload XML button, and select the checkbox for the setting.

Comment: it does not work.. I think I am not able to specify the application.. it is "Qt Creator", and it is located in: /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app

Comment: It worked for me when I changed the bundle identifier to org.qt-project.qtcreator. You could try disabling other applications or kernel extensions, or test if KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD is shown in EventViewer.app, or test if predefined settings like this work.

Comment: holy god. thank you it works with `org.qt-project.qtcreator` identifier

Comment: and for F2? I've tried to add those 2 lines `<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP, KeyCode::F2</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F2, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP </autogen>` but nothing..

Comment: Try KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_BRIGHTNESS_UP instead.

Answer (score 5):

### [Palua](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12)

Palua lets you change *all* function keys for *individual* apps.

> With Palua, you just need one click - or one hotkey - to toggle the mode your Fx keys are.

[image: Palua Smart Mode]

### [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/)

FunctionFlip can 'flip' *certain* function keys only instead of changing all keys, but it works for *all* apps.

> FunctionFlip individually controls your MacBook or MacBook Pro's function keys, turning special keys back to regular F-keys, or vice-versa.

[image: FunctionFlip]

> FunctionFlip's purpose is simply to disable the special features — rewind, play, mute, etc. — on the function keys. For example, if you "flip" F7, F8, and F9, those keys — only those keys — will revert back to normal F keys. Press the fn key with the special key to get the special function back. That is, the "special" and "normal" functions are flipped.

Answer (score 1):

The "Use all F1..." method is probably the best way to go. It'll be mildly inconvenient in other applications, but it may make sense for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

1. Click Apple at the top left of the Mac Menu
2. Click "System Preferences..."
3. Select the Keyboard Icon
4. Check the "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard key functions".

Comment: This overrides all function keys at all times for every program, the OP really needs it just to work on F4, and even then just for that one App if possible

Answer (score 0):

How about using the default Excel for Mac shortcut?

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>